# Match number between '<<' (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

> All files          |  100 <<222>>

And would like to match the number between `<< >>`

How can I do that?

So far I tried this expression `(?<<)(.*?)(?>>)`

Comment: You can try (?<=<<)(.\d+)(?=>>) That worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `<` is a special character, which needs to be escaped. Also, the `?` in the first and third group are invalid:

```
(\<\<)(?P<number>\d*?)(\>\>)
```

Additionally, I named the group with the number and used `\d` to match digits instead of `*`. I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/tN0bG9/1).

Comment: You are on the exact solution +1 .

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
In [1]: match = re.compile(r'<<(\d+)>>')
In [2]: match.findall('100 <<222>>')
Out[2]: ['222']
```

Regex model

```
<<(\d+)>>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/igWnc7UKlm_2GgcB)